# Attaching a debugger to a container/instance running on a K8s Pod?

Tags: visual-studio-code, kubernetes, debugging, containers, gdbserver

From VS Code on my local machine I am trying to attach a debugger to a remote process running in a container/Pod, or attach to a gdb/gdbserver attached to a process running in a container/Pod.

The project is written in C++, and VS Code has support for debugging processes using GDB.

My topology looks like this:

```
 -----------         ---------------        ------------------------------------
| localhost | <---> | access server | <--> | worker node                        |   
| (VS Code) |       | (ubuntu box)  |      | (k8s node)  <-> POD <-> Container  |
 -----------         ---------------        ------------------------------------
```

Access to the container/Pod has to be done via "access server" (aka. jumpbox) for security reasons. VS Code is configured and is able to connect to the worker node via access server (via VS Code ssh config option `-ProxyCommand ssh -W %h:%p Access_Server`), have K8s extension working too and can see the cluster info and interact with it.

In terms of connectivity, I can get VS Code to connect to the worker node but not to Container itself. Where debugger could be attached to running process.

I have tried running gdbserver on the container and opening the required port, and since VS Code can connect to the node in theory it should see the gdbserver but this fails with nondescript error.

I have tried to use gdb from an interactive shell, but due to the nature and scope of project a modern gui debugger is really my best option for success.

This is my first project in a cloud env so its a bit new to me, please do not assume I know things, and kindly provide guidance if it seems like I may be unaware of something you believe is obvious. I have inherited a project with not much info about devops, and no one here to ask. I've tried following some guides but nothing I've tried has really worked.

What would be the most appropriate approach to debugging given such a setup?

Comment: You said `"I have tried running gdbserver on the container and opening the required port, and since VS Code can connect to the node in theory it should see the gdbserver but this fails"` -- it may not be obvious since you are new to k8s, but pods have their own network separate from the node(host) network. the cluster also has its own network separate from the pod and host(node) net. Your localhost/jumpbox would only have access to the host net, to access ports "inside" the pod you need to port-forward. `kubectl port-forward` can forward any port **described in the yaml spec.**

Comment: I know, it is not "the full answer" you are looking for, I am only trying to help guide you toward a final solution since I am also interested to know how this is done. Everything I have found online is specific to docker, and many of those solutions are "cheating" in a way that it only works under docker, or, only works when two pods can interact with one another on the same physical host (which are both bad assumptions to make in non-docker k8s environment.)

Answer (score 1):

You shuold use kubectl port forward functionality, to forward your local gdb connection to the gdbserver running inside the container.

Another solution that might work:
If you have KubeAPI access and are running on Linux/macOS (or can use WSL) I'd suggest to check out https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=MetalBear.mirrord - It enables you to run your process locally in the context of the existing pod, then you can attach a debugger to it (or just run it using the debugger with mirrord)

Full disclosure, I'm developing mirrord.

Comment: Port-forward should technically work, but you may find that it doesn't work in practice. I've tried to use port-forward for the Java debugger protocol connection between a container and Eclipse, and it starts up and works for a few seconds, but always dies with Broken Pipe errors after a few seconds. Things like REST endpoint ports work fine, but a "chatty" protocol like the JDP may not work. I would imagine the gdb debugger protocol probably would have similar results.

Comment: Another alternative is https://www.telepresence.io/ . With this, you can substitute a container in the cluster with a local process, which would be much easier to debug. That won't be exactly the same as debugging the container directly, but it will be better than nothing.